# How to get XSSFWorkBook name in java?

Tags: java, filenames, xssf

I am getting a xssfwookbook from java program.I need to get the name of that wookbook(file name).But wookbook.getname() method is not there like other file.getName();
How can I get the name of the excel file which I am getting as a woorkbook?

Answer (score 0):

A workbook is simply a file and does not have any other name apart from its filename.  You need the filename to open the workbook, so you must already have it.

If you call

```
public DirectoryNode getRootDirectory()
```

you can also get relevant information like `getPath()`